# File::Find::Rule and file separator

Tags: perl, file-find

I am using `File::Find::Rule` on Strawberry Perl Windows.

when I run the following code:

```
@files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                              ->in( $dir );
                              foreach my $file (@files){
                              say $file;
                              }
```

I get the list of files in this format:

```
C:\data\mydata\file/1.xls
```

and not this format:

```
C:\data\mydata\file\1.xls
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem is your expectations. `C:\data\mydata\file/1.xls` is a perfectly valid Windows path.

File::Spec can normalize the path for you.

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
$path = canonpath($path);
```

or

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
@files = map { canonpath($_) } @files;
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause is probably manual concatenation of the dir and the filename. You can fix it using File::Spec:

```
use File::Spec;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->in( $dir );
foreach my $file (@files){
    say File::Spec->catfile($file);
}
```